# How to select particular region in bitmap and remove background color in Android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm developing an Android application in which user can upload his photo and apply some color filters and save to his gallery. I need user to select some region in bitmap and change its background color and save to gallery. How can I get this?

Comment: What is the meaning of changing its background? overwrite region with a color?

Comment: @coderhyme Yes.overwrite with color

Answer (score 1):

The following example assumes your area is bound by a triangle.
There are also addRect addCircle, addOval, etc for a path.

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

Path p = new Path();
p.moveTo(x1, y1);
p.lineTo(x2, y2);
p.lineTo(x3, y3);
p.close();

canvas.clipPath(p);
canvas.drawColor(myColour);
```

For a rectangular region the code is much simpler:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(myColour);  // Style.FILL by default
canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
```

Comment: Thanks.But the region may be anything,how we draw the region.

Comment: You can make a region with Path class like example above.

Comment: For predefined shape i can make a region like above,but how we make region for irregular shape. ontouch event i have to create a region.

Comment: onTouch gives you a set of dots, which form a polygon, so the example above works. The only concern is that the polygon might not be convex.